# How to automatically open child node after insert into root node in jtree?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtree, expand

When I insert child nodes into root node, the root node is not automatically expanded.

I want to expand root node automatically after insert child nodes into root node.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No default automatics, you have to implement it yourself. Several possibilities, all involving a custom TreeModelListener registered to the tree's model. The listener acts on receiving a treeNodesInserted

- manually expands the JTree to the path
- set the selection to the path (implicitly expands the tree if its expandsSelectedPaths property is true which is the default)

Code snippet:

```
class MyTreeModelListener implements TreeModelListener {

     public void treeNodesInserted(TreeModelEvent e) {
          // first option
          myTree.expandPath(e.getPath());
          // second option
          myTree.setSelectionPath(e.getPath());
     }

     // empty implementation of other listener methods
     ...
} 

// usage
myTree.getModel().addTreeModelListener(new MyTreeModelListener());
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Simple, concise, and direct to the point; While still providing all information needed for a successful implementation. +1

Comment: I can't get this to work, so I tried to expand all rows, and that doesn't work for me either. In my testing, it looks like treeNodesInserted is called after the nodes have been added to the TreeModel, but before the JTree (actually, a jidesoft NavigationTree) has added the rows, so the rows aren't available to be expanded. Am I missing something?